# How to use word boundary in awk when using data from variable

Tags: bash, awk

I have problem with word boundary in `awk`

```
var="blue"
```

```
cat file
test
blue more
bluegrass not
yes red
more blue
fine blue, not
```

I need only lines with  `blue`, more or less.

If I do:

```
awk '/\<blue\>/' file
blue more
more blue
fine blue, not
```

I get the output what I need (but this is without using variable).

But how to do this with a variable?

Here are some of my tests:

```
awk '$0~"\<"test"\>"' test="$var" file
awk '$0~/\</test/\>/' test="$var" file
awk '{a="\<"test"\>"} $0~a' test="$var" file
```

All of these fails.

Needs `awk` only, since this is part of a larger test.

---

Update.
It seems that some of my variable does contains a `+` sing. This brakes the solution from `Ed`

```
var="blue+"
```

```
cat file
test
blue+green more
bluegrass not
yes red
more blue+
fine blue+, not
```

```
awk -v test="$var" '$0~"\\<"test"\\>"' file
blue+green more
more blue+
fine blue+, not
```

Comment: What does `+` mean in that context? Is it a literal plus sign or a regexp metacharacter meaning 1 or more repetitions?

Comment: @EdMorton This is the name of some product, and the `+` is part of the name to tell its a better model :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v test="$var" '$0~"\\<"test"\\>"' tfile
```

Remember strings used in regexp contexts get parsed twice, once when read and again when executed, so you need to escape everything twice if it needs to be escaped.

Also note that `\<` is gawk-only.

Given the updated info that the text you want to search for can contain RE metacharacters you need to either

1. escape all RE metacharacters that could appear in your text, or
2. treat it as a string

Escaping RE metacharaters is trivial if you only have a couple in specific contexts to worry about and I'm sure you can figure that out, but is difficult (impossible?) in general due to the context-sensitive nature of the characters so I'll focus on how to detect a string that's not part of a longer "word":

```
awk -v test="$var" '
    (s=index($0,test)) &&                            # test exists and is neither
    ((s>1?substr($0,s-1,1):"") !~ /[[:alnum:]_]/) && # preceded by a word char nor
    (substr($0,s+length(test),1) !~ /[[:alnum:]_]/)  # succeeded by a word char
'
```

Comment: Perfect.  Is this possible with plain  `awk`?

Comment: Not exactly. For just searching you can use `$0~"(^|[^[:alnum:]_])"test"([^[:alnum:]_]|$)"'` but that unfortunately sucks up the bounding char(s) if you were using it to print the matching string using `match()` or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton I was just going to publish that answer! `:P`.

Comment: See my updated post.  Seems that some of my var does contains `+`, and that brakes the solution.

Comment: It works fine, some complicated, but works :)   I did try escaping the  `+` but did not work.  `awk -v test="$var" 'BEGIN {gsub(/\+/,"\\\\&",test);print test} $0~"\\<"test"\\>"'` First  `print` is just to see that the escaping goes into the variable.

Comment: Interesting - try it without a variable: `gawk '/\<blue\+\>/' file` doesn't match any of the text while `gawk '/\<blue\+/'` matches all occurrences of `blue+`. Seems like some kind of interaction between `\+` and `\>` - I'm guessing you can't use word-delimiters on either side of a non-word character.

Comment: Final and working solution.  I know that the pattern is at the end of the line and pattern comes after "=" and I do use `RS=""` to make works with groups.  So the I got: `awk -v test="$var" 'BEGIN {gsub(/\+/,"\\\\&",test)} $0~"= *"test" *\n"'`  It now works fine with the `+`  Thanks :)