# Grep to exclude comment like # and -- with trailing spaces and within line

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I tried to grep the word inside file which contains # and -- as a comment. The command that I used is 
`grep "^[^#]" -H -R -I "pathtofile" | grep "^[^--]" | grep -in ${1} | awk -F : ' { print $2 } ' | uniq)` 
which will print the file name of specific word. However, if there is a line like this

```
        --test_specific_word_test test
```

The code above will treat above code as not to skip it. This case also apply to where the comment is in line with the code like `var=1 --comment`.

Should I use sed to delete comment line first or use just grep.

The downside is I have a significant amount of file to search and GNU grep is 2.0 and I can't upgrade the grep version because I don't have permission.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. `grep '^[^--]'` looks like a mistake -- do you mean `grep -ve '--'`? Anyway, if you are using Awk in this pipeline, you might as well refactor all of it to an Awk script (and then it won't matter which `grep` version you have. As an aside, 2.0 alone doesn't reveal anything -- do you mean you have GNU `grep` 2.0?)

Comment: @tripleee. that statement is for beginning of the line and negate -- in the bracket. Am I misunderstood my interpretation? how can I use awk to accomplish this? I need it to print file name can awk do it?. Yes I have GNU grep 2.0

Comment: It looks for a character which is not `-` and not `-` which is obviously redundant. Did you expect `--` which isn't at beginning of line to be filtered out by this?

Comment: It's not obvious what your pipeline is doing or what it's doing wrong without more detailed requirements. But for example, `grep -nv 'regex' | grep 'poo' | awk '{ print $2 }'` can be refactored to `awk '!/regex/ && /poo/ { print FNR ":" $2 }'`

Comment: Keep in mind that `[--]` is exactly the same as `[-]` -- brackets define a *character class*, which matches exactly one character -- which set of characters that one character can be depending on the content of those brackets.

Comment: And yes, the variable `FILENAME` in Awk contains the current input filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you've provided uses grep 4 times. You can skip commented lines with a single grep command:

```
grep -v "^ *\(--\|#\)" "pathtofile"
```

To print the filenames containing `word1` use `cut` like so:

```
grep -Hv "^ *\(--\|#\)" filenames | grep "word1" | cut -d: -f1
```

To skip inline comments use `sed`:

```
sed "s/\(.*\)\(--\|#\).*/\1/g" inputfile
```

Sample input:

```
word1
   word2
  -word3 # inline comment
   #comment1
   --comment2
 #comment3
```

output:

```
word1
   word2
  -word3
```

Comment: This still doesn't resolve the `var=2 -- comment` case, though I still don't pretend to understand exactly how the OP would like for that to be resolved, or what other corner cases there are.

Answer (score 0):

If in fact you are attempting to parse a programming language's source files, you are probably better off using a proper parser.  Here is an attempt at refactoring your code into an Awk script, with several guesses as to what exactly the script should actually do.

```
find pathtofile -type f -exec awk -v word="$1" -F : '
    # this doesn't reimplement grep -I though
    { sub("(#|--).*", "") } # remove comments
    tolower($0) ~ tolower(word) && !($2 in a) { print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $2; a[$2] }' {} +
```

This has the obvious flaw that if the programming language allows for `#` or `--` in quoted strings and doesn't regard those as comments, the script will do the wrong thing.

There are no word boundaries in your script, so I didn't put any in mine either.  This means if `word="dog"` then it will print any string which contains the three adjacent letters d-o-g in this order, even in substring matches like "doggone" or "endogenous".  If that's not what you want, you can add word boundary markers -- if you have GNU Awk, you can say `BEGIN { word = "\\<" word "\\> }` at the beginning of the script; or [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705084/how-to-use-word-boundary-in-awk-when-using-data-from-variable)

The technique to add the key to an array and only print the key if it wasn't already in the array is a common way to implement `uniq`.  This will fail if `find` returns so many files that it will end up running more than one instance of `awk` -- this will be controlled by the value of `ARG_MAX` of your kernel.